# Laravel - Diference betwen static methods and static instance() method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am seeing this practice in many Laravel applications, and I don't know the diferences o the reasons to use this.

Instead of having public static methods in the class, many people code only one static function that retrieves an instance of a class an this instace call the function.

This classes have no properties or anything that is needed to make the functions work, so I do not understand why use this way to work. I think this make code more dificult to read, in many cases.

Example, I see this laravel implementantion:

```
class MyClass
{
    public static function instance()
    {
        return new MyClass();
    }

    public function myStuff()
    {
        //my stuff
    }
}

//Calling it
MyClass::instance()->myStuff();
```

I think it would be more readable and same result making all it with static functions, like:

```
class MyClass
{    
    public static function myStuff()
    {
        //my stuff
    }
}

//Calling it
MyClass::myStuff();
```

What do you think about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cases with chained, optional methods, it makes a lot of sense to have a constructor for the class, then have the methods as non-static and self-returning.

```php
class Burger
{
    private Collection $ingredients;
    
    public static function instance()
    {
        $burger = new self;
        $burger->ingredients = collect([]);
        return $burger;
    }

    public function addCheese() : self
    {
        $this->ingredients->push('cheese');
        return $this;
    }
    
    public function addMeat() : self
    {
        $this->ingredients->push('meat');
        return $this;
    }
}

$burger = Burger::instance()
    ->addCheese()
    ->addMeat()
    ->addCheese();
```

Many classes in Laravel use this pattern, including Eloquent Models.

```php
$posts = Post::query()
    ->where('author_id', 2)
    ->whereHas('tag', fn($tag) => $tag->where('name', 'games')
    ->get();
```

A traditional constructor may be used instead of a static method, but then you would have to instantiate it using the keyword `new` and parentheses, which doesn't look as good:

```php
$burger = (new Burger)
    ->addCheese()
    ->addMeat()
    ->addCheese();
```

If the class has only the constructor and one other method, possibly it was an attempt to make it easier to automate testing for the class [by mocking it](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mocking) in the future.

Comment: Oh, I understand it now. All the examples I saw, only call to a one method, I didn't think about chained methods!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We know about your concern. It is difficult to discuss what is better, depend your project, your style, your business. But we can give you a keyword to read more about that: **`Singleton Pattern`**

Comment: You need to read more about Cohesion vs Coupling & Instance vs Static binding.